# How to assign a value in angular's $parse

Tags: angularjs

I have a string reference to one of my scope values like this:

```
var reference_string = "form.name";
```

And I want to assign a value to the object it is referencing:

```
$scope.form.name = 'newvalue';
```

Looking around, I found 2 possible solutions: [using plain JS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6491621/1097483) or using the angular [$parse](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$parse) function.

However, it seems like the $parse function only returns the value. Can I make it so that I can assign a new value?

ie. I want to do something like

```
var reference_string = "form.name";
var reference = getReference($scope, reference_string); // ideally using an angular in-built function like $parse
reference = 'newvalue'; // should have the same effect as $scope.form.name = 'newvalue';
```

Comment: Are you trying to use strings to access an object like `form['name']` ?

Comment: @TjGienger yeah, except that its in a nested format so I can't do it directly. `$scope['form.name']` won't work

Comment: did you try `$scope['form']['name']` ? I never have, just a thought

Comment: use regex to separate the original string

Comment: @TjGienger Short of using eval, I can't do that. Also I mentioned that there was a plain JS way (through parsing the string and traversing the object), which is a little hacky and I was hoping for a more elegant solution with angular's `$parse`.

Comment: This is definitely an XY question.  Why are you trying to store the name of a variable as a string and then trying to reference it later in the first place?

Comment: @Claies I wouldn't necessarily say that. I've had to do similar to marry up server-side validation messages with scoped models. Sometimes all you have is a string reference.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The object returned by `$parse` has an `assign()` method for setting values.

```
var getter = $parse(reference_string);
getter.assign($scope, 'newValue');
```

Plunker demo ~ http://plnkr.co/edit/RlhXRpJvQ69ZdEkstyq8?p=preview

Comment: Thanks! The example really helped to show how to use it.

Comment: If the reference has multiple data
{name1 : "test1",name2 : "test2"}
How does it works with this scenario...@Phil

Comment: @VenkatRJV not sure what you mean. `$parse` only supports a single expression AFAIK but you can create multiple assignment strings for the same object

Comment: @Phil where did you get avatar like that? just curious :)

Answer (score -1):

$parse is an Angular service which converts an expression into a function. The function can then be invoked and passed a context (usually scope) in order to retrieve the expression's value.
In addition, if the expression is assignable the returned function will have an assign property. The assign property is a function that can be used to change the expression's value on the given context.

[enter link description here](http://ng.malsup.com/#!/$parse-and-$eval)